# Angular 2 type script define error

Tags: angular, typescript, syntax-error

When define response data to array, error occured:

```
public esriLocation = [];
public testLocation  = [];

 this.service.getData().subscribe(
                  (response) => this.esriLocation = response.json(),
                  (error) => console.log('ESRI ERROR: ' + error)
          );

          this.testLocation = this.esriLocation.suggestions;
```

**Property 'suggestions' does not exisits on type 'any'**

Responce

```
{
    "suggestions": [{
        "text": "DEU",
        "key": "dHA9MCNsb2M9MTAzOTkwNTEjbG5nPTQ0I2xicz0xMDk6NDI2MDI4NzM=",
        "isCollection": false
    }, {
        "text": "ENG",
        "key": "dHA9MCNsb2M9MTA0MDAzOTcjbG5nPTQ0I2xicz0xMDk6NDI2MDI4NzU=",
        "isCollection": false
    }]
}
```

How to fix?

Comment: try declare `public esriLocation = {};` Also what is the value of `console.log(this.esriLocation` after the service call

Comment: try to declare like  : `public esriLocation:any; public testLocation:any; `

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Thanks it Helps!

Comment: if it work then please upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to declare like  below :

```
public esriLocation:any; 
public testLocation:any; 
    this.service.getData().subscribe(
                      (response) => {this.esriLocation = response.json()
                                     this.testLocation = this.esriLocation.suggestions;
                               },
                      (error) => console.log('ESRI ERROR: ' + error)
              );
```

Answer (score 2):

It is async by nature you need to do the assignment inside the success call back.

```
public esriLocation = [];
public testLocation  = [];

 this.service.getData().subscribe(
                  (response) => {this.esriLocation = response.json()
                                 this.testLocation = this.esriLocation.suggestions;
                           },
                  (error) => console.log('ESRI ERROR: ' + error)
          );
```

as it is async by nature you cannot guarantee that the result will be available after the subscribe block, if it is available and you find it not assigned properly check if you are getting a JSON object not the string.

Comment: check if you have the typeof this.esriLocation is actually an object

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd  provided a fix. Thank you for help, your answer are helpfull too